# PERC H700: "Virtual disk creation failed" Why?

Tags: dell-perc

I try to create a new VD on a drive from the PERC config. I get:

"Virtual disk creation failed"

The drive has been used before in another system.

What do I need to clear, before I can use the drive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to PERC config.

F2 > Manage Preserved Cache > DISCARD CACHE

Insert drive.

F2 > Create new VD

If you still get "Virtual disk creation failed"

CTRL-N, CTRL-N, CTRL-N

F2 > Clear Foreign config

And now you should be able to:

F2 > Create new VD